# Unable to trigger .ajaxComplete() function with jQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to use ajax function to check name availability, but I was unable to prompt out the correct message. It is always stuck on "loading" icon there. I had tried to troubleshoot my code, and it seem like it unable to trigger the `.ajaxComplete` function. I have no clue on this, please point out if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks

Here is my Ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        pic1 = new Image(16, 16); 
        pic1.src = "assets/img/loader.gif";

        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#packageName").change(function() { 

        var pName = $("#packageName").val();

        if(pName.length >= 4)
        {
        $("#status").html('<img src="assets/img/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...'); 
            $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "checkPackageAvaibility.php",  
            data: "packageName="+pName,

            success: function(msg){  

           $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
            if(msg == "OK")
            { 
                $("#packageName").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                $("#packageName").addClass("object_ok");
                $(this).html('&nbsp;<img src="assets/img/tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
            }  
            else  
            {  
                $("#packageName").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                $("#packageName").addClass("object_error");
                $(this).html(msg);
            }  

           });

         } 

          }); 

        }
        else
            {
            $("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
            $("#packageName").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
            $("#packageName").addClass("object_error");
            }

        });

        });

        //-->
        </script>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
     include "include/session.php";
     include 'include/dbConnect.php';

     global $dbLink;

     if(isset($_POST["packageName"])){

         $pacName = $_POST["packageName"];

         $query= ("SELECT * FROM Package WHERE package_name = '$pacName'");
         $sql_check = sqlsrv_query($dbLink,$query);

         $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($sql_check);

         if($rows ===true )
        {
        echo '<font color="red">The nickname <STRONG>'.$pacName.'</STRONG> is already in use.</font>';
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'OK';
        }
     }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind [ajaxComplete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to the document

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached
>   to document.

So

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mjhe25n0/)

---

You don't need `ajaxComplete()`, instead just use the done callback like

```
pic1 = new Image(16, 16);
pic1.src = "assets/img/loader.gif";

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#packageName").change(function () {
        var pName = $("#packageName").val();
        if (pName.length >= 4) {
            $("#status").html('<img src="assets/img/loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "checkPackageAvaibility.php",
                data: "packageName=" + pName
            }).done(function (msg) {
                if (msg == "OK") {
                    $("#packageName").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
                    $("#packageName").addClass("object_ok");
                    $('#status').html('&nbsp;<img src="assets/img/tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
                } else {
                    $("#packageName").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
                    $("#packageName").addClass("object_error");
                    $('#status').html(msg);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#status").html('<font color="red">The username should have at least <strong>4</strong> characters.</font>');
            $("#packageName").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
            $("#packageName").addClass("object_error");
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: sorry for my poor english, what document you mean?

Comment: @MarcusTan the document object

Comment: then my "#status" should change to what?

Comment: @MarcusTan use `$("#status").html(msg);` instead of `$(this).html(msg);`

Comment: How about my $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)  ?

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching an ajaxComplete event handler inside the function that triggers when your ajax request is complete.

Apart from the fact that you cannot do that, you don't need that either, the `success` function is all you need in this case:

```
success: function(msg) {  
    if(msg == "OK") { 
        $("#packageName").removeClass('object_error'); // if necessary
        $("#packageName").addClass("object_ok");
        $("#status").html('&nbsp;<img src="assets/img/tick.gif" align="absmiddle">');
    } else {  
        $("#packageName").removeClass('object_ok'); // if necessary
        $("#packageName").addClass("object_error");
        $("#status").html(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had try this method before, still my it never remove any class and stuck on loading icon

Comment: @MarcusTan This is the correct way, if it does not work, you need to check what `msg` contains exactly. So add `console.log(msg);` before your `if` statement and see what you get in the console. Note that any output in your php script except `OK` (spaces, new-lines, php warnings) will cause your `if` statement to fail.